# How to change fragment in navigation drawer from dialogFragment while using tab layout as parent?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-dialogfragment, android-tablayout

I am having issues after adding tab layout to my fragment, changing fragment from a fragment dialog does no action neither throws exception.

code in fragment containing the tab layout:

```
    public void addFragment(tabChildFragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        fragment.setType(title);
        fragment.setParentView((ViewGroup)getView().getParent());

    }
```

code in tabChildFragment:

```
public void setParentView(ViewGroup parentView) {
    this.parentView = parentView;
}

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                                DialogFrag dialog = new DialogFrag(new DismissHandler(),parentView);
                                                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                dialog.show(ft, null);}}
```

And the DialogFrag code that should replace the tabLayoutFragment with the Login Fragment:

```
Fragment myFragment = new Login();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(parentView.getId(), myFragment)
                        .commit();
                dismiss();
```

Comment: you want to change your fragment  from dialog?

Comment: @saeed Yes, and it was working before adding the tab layout fragment as parent, by sending the viewgroup from the tabChildFragment, By passing the parent view from the tabChildFragment to the dialog, but after adding the tablayout, thought passing the parent viewgroup from the tablayoutFragment to tabChildFragment then passing it to dialog will give same action but it didn't.

Comment: your click event is working?   sorry i did int fully understand your quistain it is very complex  to understand

Comment: yes it is working.